# Tax and Shipping Not yet Calculated on Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, shipping-tax, tax-calculation

Tax and Shipping Not yet Calculated on Magento 2.2.6

> Magastore one step checkout extensions

on Order Review Box there are shipping and tax not display so there are not display total amount but when order completed on order email we got there all details

[image]

Comment: Kindly check the following configuration.Store-> Configuration-> sales -> Tax -> Tax class

Comment: yes we set there but not works http://prntscr.com/mtxzie

Comment: Check all Magento tax configuration and also check all configurations of Magastore one step checkout extensions

Comment: I'm checked there are no options like that on extensions and as for setting I think perfect because on mail everything perfect but not fronted any other options in Magento 2 for display tax-related